# Invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, invariance

Let T be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space V over a field F such that every subspace of V is invariant under T then how to prove T is digonalizable ? Is the converse true ?

Comment: Hint: If every subspace is invariant that includes one-dimensional subspaces...

Comment: If T : V -> V is diagonalizable linear operator  then every one dimensional subspace of V is invariant under T ?

Comment: Of course not. There's an explicit counterexample in Martin's answer, which you seem to have gone through a few hours ago...

Comment: Yes i forgot thank you

Comment: That was for every and this is about one dimensional subspace ..

Comment: Sigh. What is the dimension of $\{[a,a]:a\in\Bbb R\}$?

Comment: One . W={av : a is in F } is also one dimensional but its invariant under T

Comment: No, $W$ is not invariant unless $v$ is an eigenvector for $T$. You're repeating the same errors you made a few hours ago in your discussion with Martin. Possibly you should first make certain you know exactly what it means to say a subspace is invariant under $T$ and then stop and think about all this for a while...

Comment: Yes v is a eigen vector  and a is an eigen value so that T(v)=av then this is true

Comment: You're not making any sense here. When you write $W=\{av:a\in F\}$ you cannot then say $a$ is an eigenvalue; in the definition of $W$ you're talking about _every_ $a\in F$. In any case, I have no idea what your point is.

Comment: Let $v \in V$ be non zero eigen vector of T corresponding to eigen value a so that T(v)=av . Then let W={av : a is in F } be the1-dimensional subspace of vctor space $V$ generated by v . Then W is a T-invariant subspace .

Comment: Now i understood .. thank u very much for helping ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v_1,\ldots,v_n $ is a basis, then for each $j $ we have $Tv_j=\lambda _jv_j $ for some $\lambda \in F $, since the subspace  $Fv_j $ is invariant. So $T $ is diagonalizable.

This property means that $T $ is diagonalizable in every basis, so it is very strong; so the converse does not hold. Let $V=\mathbb R^2$ and $$T=\begin {bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end {bmatrix}. $$ Consider the subspace  $$V_0=\left\{(a,a)^T: a\in\mathbb R\right\}. $$ Then  $T $ is diagonalizable (in the canonical basis) but $V_0$ is not invariant.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate how $V_0$ is not invariant ..

Comment: In fact $T$ must be a multiple of the identity...

Comment: What? $f(v)v$ is not even linear!

Comment: Btw, the property does imply that $T$ is a "constant" multiple of $I$. I've posted a detailed proof.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate how $V_0$ is not invariant .. ??

Comment: Did you try? Do you think it is invariant?

Comment: For any $(a,a)^T$ in $V_0$ we have $T(a,a) = \lambda(a,a) = (\lambda a,\lambda a) \in V_0/$ which implies $T(V_0)$ is a subset of $V_0$

Comment: Where did you get $\lambda  $ from $T=\begin {bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end {bmatrix} $?

Comment: I took any arbitrary value $\lambda$

Comment: And why would you do that? If you are given $T $,  you cannot just choose how it acts.

Comment: Then how to do ?

Comment: $$\begin {bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end {bmatrix}\begin {bmatrix}a\\ a\end {bmatrix}=\begin {bmatrix}a\\ 2a\end {bmatrix}. $$

Comment: I didnt think of it Thank you so much for helping

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

The property implies that $T=cI$ for some scalar $c$.

First, since every subspace is invariant, every (non-zero) vector is an eigenvector. Now suppose $u$ and $v$ are independent, $Tu=au$, $Tv=bv$. Then $$T(u+v)=au+bv.$$But we also have $$T(u+v)=c(u+v)$$for some scalar $c$. Independence shows that $a=c=b$. So $T=c I$.